# Send video attachment using EWS C#

Tags: c#, xml, email, smtp, exchangewebservices

I've been trying to send an email via EWS in C#
I manage to send a casual email with html body, but whenever I attach multimedia to it I get this error
*"Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML.'
ServiceXmlDeserializationException: The expected XML node type was XmlDeclaration, but the actual type is Element.*

But when I attach .txt file or .docx file it's fine, only when I attach multimedia files like .mp4 .jpg .png

And the files are small sized as well.

Would love to get some help on this.

Thanks

Comment: The code is trying to deserialize the XML.  The xml declaration is "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" which appears to be missing and first tag is an actual element.

Comment: @jdweng I actually fetched the log and the xml had that statment:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

But then in the attachment section there's a loooooooooooot of characters, I assume it's the byte array of the multimedia file, but I'm still confused why it's not working

Comment: Probably something to do with namespace.